# How unique a 5-digit mt_rand() number is?

Tags: php

I am just wondering, how unique is a mt_rand() number is, if you draw 5-digits number?
In the example, I tried to get a list of 500 random numbers with this function and some of them are repeated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$errors = array();
$uniques = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 500; ++$i)
{
    $random_code = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
    if(!in_array($random_code, $uniques))
    {
        $uniques[] = $random_code;
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = $random_code;
    }
}

/**
 * If you get any data in this array, it is not exactly unique
 * Run this script for few times and you may see some repeats
 */
print_r($errors);
?>
```

How many digits may be required to ensure that the first 500 random numbers drawn in a loop are unique?

Comment: A random number is not guaranteed to be "unique".

Comment: See the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for some math behind the issue.

Comment: Random != unique. You may get a more useful answer if you say what you are using the numbers for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use range, shuffle, and slice?

```
<?php

$uniques = range(10000, 99999);
shuffle($uniques);
$uniques = array_slice($uniques, 0, 500);

print_r($uniques);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/11fd1213b83877):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 91652
    [1] => 87559
    [2] => 68494
    [3] => 70561
    [4] => 16514
    [5] => 71605
    [6] => 96725
    [7] => 15908
    [8] => 14923
    [9] => 10752
    [10] => 13816
    *** truncated ***
)
```

This method is less expensive as it does not search the array each time to see if the item is already added or not. That said, it does make this approach less "random". More information should be provided on where these numbers are going to be used. If this is an online gambling site, this would be the worst! However if this was used in returning "lucky" numbers for a horoscope website, I think it would be fine.

Furthermore, this method could be extended, changing the shuffle method to use mt_rand (where as the original method simply used rand). It may also use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes, but that might be overkill.

Comment: @hek2mgl, Where did OP mention about _Uniform Distribution_ ??? OP says.. _I tried to get a list of 500 random numbers with this function and some of them are repeated._

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran But this numbers aren't random. Just their order is randomized.

Comment: How does this prevent duplicates of random numbers?

Comment: @JaredFarrish An array is filled with numbers from 10,000 to 99,999. Since the numbers are sequential at the beginning (eg. 1, 2, 3...), there are no duplicates to begin with. Then, when I shuffle the array, and get the first 500 elements, I should have an array of 500 elements with no duplicates, and the numbers shouldn't be in order.

Comment: I really feel bad when such good answer is being **downvoted**

Comment: You're assuming the `shuffle()` algorithm is suitably random for the purposes needed. Don't know if it is, but I suspect it's not very random.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I didn't voted here but this answer isn't good, it is wrong. It does not answer the question. Josh's answer is correct.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I agree with you, this answer does not mention anything about `mt_rand()` functions _uniqueness_ . This is just an _another_ way of solving the problem.

Comment: @MarcAudet - You would need to read elsewhere on how randomness and suitability is determined (I am not an expert), but one thing that makes me skeptical is fit; each entry must be fitted once and only once in each shuffle (and must be represented), meaning every number is represented. Contra to the OP's desire, this reduces the "randomness" since duplicates are truly random, where fitness in the group is not represented. This may be equivalent to the other answer (I do not have the math skills to speculate), but my guess is it's worse.

Comment: This method is an approach I feel is appropriate, unless further information is provided by the question (such as where these numbers are going to be used, such as online gambling, random post selection, etc). Continuously search an array that is reaching a size of 500 elements is expensive, so it depends highly on how random these numbers need to be. If you do require them to be a little more random, I don't see why not another implementation of shuffle could be accomplished.

Comment: @DaveChen Add your last comment to the answer and you get my upvote. You are right, it is important to know where this numbers should be used. There might be many cases where your solution is ok - and fast.

Comment: @DaveChen - It is clever; I will probably stash it away somewhere for when I need something like it. `:)` There is perhaps a difference between card game randomness and cryptographic randomness. However, I would note that simply calling `shuffle()` again will accomplish nothing.

Comment: The big factor I'd see in choosing your approach is your n = number of needed values. If you're n=3, then this is a really over-the-top approach, and I assume perf + randomness are important as mt_rand() was chosen over rand(). If you have n=89999, then the do{}while() solution for picking new numbers will run at a snail's pace. n=500 seems way too low for a shuffle(range()) to make sense.

Comment: @JaredFarrish The quality of how well the `shuffle` function works is limited to how well the random number generator used to select (order the permuation) the 5-digit numbers works.  Digital random number generators are not perfect, but most of the time, they work well enough.  If I used the `shuffle` function millions of times and plot the distribution of the resulting combinations, it should look pretty even.

Answer (score 7):

If numbers are truly random, then there's a probability that numbers will be repeated. It doesn't matter how many digits there are -- adding more digits makes it much less likely there will be a repeat, but it's always a possibility.

You're better off checking if there's a conflict, then looping until there isn't like so:

```
$uniques = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
    do {
        $code = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
    } while(in_array($code, $uniques));
    $uniques[] = $code
}
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is definitely correct but having this check implemented, they are not uniform distributed random numbers anymore.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I think the OP does not care about uniform distribution, He needs just unique 500 random numbers and the code of _Josh_ solves the purpose though.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran After thinking about it I would also say this answer is ok. A pure uniform distribution was not requested in the question, you are right with this.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou What about this: http://3v4l.org/eBpZt ? This would not require to search through the array again and again.

Comment: @hek2mgl The issue would be that you might not get 500 elements each time. [Clicky](http://3v4l.org/U2Uld).

Comment: @DaveChen What about this? http://3v4l.org/Iq3XO.. However, I expect yours still (much) faster. Let's benchmark it?

Comment: @hek2mgl Crazy! If you posted that as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks for your upvote! But check the "real" benchmark: http://3v4l.org/IHKQY .. Isn't this crazy!? :D

Comment: @hek2mgl I also upvoted Josh's post from before as well. I had a hunch that his answer might be the fastest -- simply because the number of elements was smaller. If we were to graph number of elements over time, Josh's would sky rocket.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52446/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-dave-chen)

Answer (score 3):

The birthday paradox is at play here. If you pick a random number from 10000-99999 500 times, there's a good chance of duplicates.

**Intuitive idea with small numbers**

If you flip a coin twice, you'll get a duplicate about half the time. If you roll a six-sided die twice, you'll get a duplicate 1/6 of the time. If you roll it 3 times, you'll get a duplicate 4/9 (44%) of the time. If you roll it 4 times you'll get at least one duplicate 13/18 (63.33%). Roll it a fifth time and it's 49/54 (90.7%). Roll it a sixth time and it's 98.5%. Roll it a seventh time and it's 100%.

If you take replace the six-sided die with a 20-sided die, the probabilities grow a bit more slowly, but grow they do. After 3 rolls you have a 14.5% chance of duplicates. After 6 rolls it's 69.5%. After 10 rolls it's 96.7%, near certainty.

**The math**

Let's define a function `f(num_rolls, num_sides)` to generalize this to any number of rolls of any random number generator that chooses out of a finite set of choices. We'll define `f(num_rolls, num_sides)` to be the probability of getting no duplicates in `num_rolls` of a `num_sides`-side die.

Now we can try to build a recursive definition for this. To get `num_rolls` unique numbers, you'll need to first roll `num_rolls-1` unique numbers, then roll one more unique number, now that `num_rolls-1` numbers have been taken. Therefore

```
f(num_rolls, num_sides) = 
  f(num_rolls-1, num_sides) * (num_sides - (num_rolls - 1)) / num_sides
```

Alternately,

```
f(num_rolls + 1, num_side) = 
  f(num_rolls, num_sides) * (num_sides - num_rolls) / num_sides
```

This function follows a logistic decay curve, starting at 1 and moving very slowly (since `num_rolls` is very low, the change with each step is very small), then slowly picking up speed as `num_rolls` grows, then eventually tapering off as the function's value gets closer and closer to 0.

I've created a Google Docs spreadsheet that has this function built in as a formula to let you play with this here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bNJ5RFBsXrBr_1BEXgWGein4iXtobsNjw9dCCVeI2_8

**Tying this back to your specific problem**

You've generated rolled a 90000-sided die 500 times. The spreadsheet above suggests you'd expect at least one duplicate pair about 75% of the time assuming a perfectly random mt_rand. Mathematically, the operation your code was performing is **choosing N elements from a set *with replacement***. In other words, you pick a random number out of the bag of 90000 things, write it down, then put it back in the bag, then pick another random number, repeat 500 times. It sounds like you wanted all of the numbers to be distinct, in other words you wanted to **choose N elements from a set *without replacement***. There are a few algorithms to do this. Dave Chen's suggestion of shuffle and then slice is a relatively straightforward one. Josh from Qaribou's suggestion of separately rejecting duplicates is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your question deals with a variation of the "Birthday Problem" which asks if there are N students in a class, what is the probability that at least two students have the same birthday? See [Wikipedia: The "Birthday Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

You can easily modify the formula shown there to answer your problem. Instead of having 365 equally probable possibilities for the birthday of each student, you have 90001 (=99999-10000+2) equally probable integers that can be generated between 10000 and 99999. The probability that if you generate 500 such numbers that *at least* two numbers will be the same is:

P(500)= 1- 90001! / ( 90001^n (90001 - 500)! ) = 0.75

So there is a 75% chance that at least two of the 500 numbers that you generate will be the same or, in other words, only a 25% chance that you will be successful in getting 500 different numbers with the method you are currently using.

As others here have already suggested, I would suggest checking for repeated numbers in your algorithm rather than just blindly generating random numbers and hoping that you don't have a match between any pair of numbers.